# Understand 304 response - not modified?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, signalr

I am running the following script on the client-side and the script is failing to update, when there is change in the database.  I debugged the script using DevTools and discovered my Jquery scripts are responding back as "304 not modified".  Does this issue, indicate why the client-side content is failing to update.

```
 <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
 <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.          
    var notifications = $.connection.NotificationHub;
    // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
    notifications.client.recieveNotification = function (role, descrip) {
        // Add the message to the page.                    
        $('#spanNewMessages').text(role);
        $('#spanNewCircles').text(descrip);            
    };
    // Start the connection.
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        notifications.server.sendNotifications();
        alert("Notifications have been sent.");

    }).fail(function (e) {
        alert(e);
    });
    //$.connection.hub.start();
});
  </script>
  <h1>New Notifications</h1>
  <div>

  <br />
  <b>New   <span id="spanNewMessages"></span> = role.</b><br />
  <b>New   <span id="spanNewCircles"></span> = descrip.</b><br />   
  </div>
```

Hub Class:

```
 [HubName("NotificationHub")]
public class notificationHub : Hub
{
    string role = "";
    string descrip = "";

    [HubMethodName("sendNotifications")]
    public void SendNotifications()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dummyConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {

            string query = "SELECT top 1 [role],[description] FROM [dbo].[User] order by uploadDate desc";
            connection.Open();
            SqlDependency.Start(GetConnectionString());

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {

                try
                {
                    command.Notification = null;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();
                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    dt.Load(reader);
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        role = dt.Rows[0]["role"].ToString();
                        descrip = dt.Rows[0]["description"].ToString();

                    }

                    connection.Close();

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }  
        }

        Clients.All.RecieveNotification(role, descrip);
    }

    [HubMethodName("onStatusChanged")]
    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Insert)

        {
            notificationHub nHub = new notificationHub();
           nHub.SendNotifications();

        }
    }
```

Please advice.  Thank you.

Comment: Where is your Server side code?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have update my question, with the server code, as requested.  please advice further, if possible.

Comment: Also it seems you have included JQuery once and then JQuery-min. Remove one of them (preferably keep JQuery minimum)

Comment: I am getting 304 response, for all three Jquery scripts.  Does this indicate an issue with the Jquery script files?

Comment: Ignore 304 response for the three jQuery scripts as this is not your problem. As @Tanmoy has stated, remove one of them. Use jquery-1.6.4.js only for debugging, and jquery-1.6.4.min.js in all other cases. The 304 response for these files is happening simply because the sever is telling the browser that it already has the latest. These are library javascript files which will not change unless you copy a new version of the file over them. The notifications are not being displayed in the browser for a different reason, but unfortunately I'm not familiar with SignalR.

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript exceptions? Have you called RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(); in the Application_Start method of the global.asax? I see that you're using SqlDependency. Have you tried removing it from the equation to see if the issue is your client code or that you haven't configured SqlDependency properly?